# If $f\in \mathfrak{F}_a$ then $f^{(n)}\in \mathfrak{F}_b$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> If $f\in \mathfrak{F}_a$ i.e. holomorphic in $\{z\in
> > \Bbb{C}:|\Im z|<a\}$ and $\exists A>0$ s.t. $|f(x+iy)|\leq
>  \dfrac{A}{1+x^2} \;\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$ and $|y|<a$, then for any
>   positive integer $n$, $f^{(n)}\in \mathfrak{F}_b$ if $0\leq b<a$.

The hint given in the book is using Cauchy inequality ($|f^{(n)}(z)|\leq \dfrac{n!\sup|f|}{R^n}$). But I have difficulty in creating the $A$ which is independent to $x$. Could you please give me some hints?